# Interrupt file download process from server?

Tags: php

Can we track when the user start downloading an file and stop the download instantly ?
I believe it is possible I am just not that familiar with PHP and my friend is offline, so I am really in need of an response.

So basically for example:

I have a file on my server called: "my_file.zip"
If any user start downloading that file "my_file.zip", server should automatically interrupt / stop the download process.

It's like when premium download servers are overloaded, they stop your download and tell you to upgrade to premium and so on, but the thing I want is only to stop/corrupt the download instantly once any user access to the file.

Any solutions regardless to this ?

Comment: Why not simply upload a corrupted file in the first place?

Comment: Because the file should not be corrupted. @Pekka웃

Comment: You would have to serve the file through a PHP script. You can then instruct the PHP script to stop serving the data (or just serve nothing). However, for this to work, you'd have to point the user to a PHP file, not the zip file, and you'd have to make the zip file inaccessible from the web. Which amounts to: you don't need to have the zip at all, just have a PHP script that serves a couple bytes of garbage

Comment: Why not just prevent the download from starting for unauthorized users?

Comment: @MikeBrant yeh that might work too!